# Память в Android

Tags: android, memory

Друзья такой вопрос, сделал приложение и при его запуске сразу начинает жрать около 45 мб оперативки(в приложении много картинок). Можно ли как-то управлять процессом загрузки ресурсов  в память? Например чтобы не используемые в данный момент ресурсы не загружать сразу в память, а по мере необходимости....

Comment: Вы ведь не путаете allocated memory и used memory?

Comment: В телефоне захожу в активные приложения, вижу там свое и напротив ОЗУ:44,85MB, такой вот показатель

Comment: Нужно больше подробностей... что за картинки? это иконки и фото или Вы вообще все фоны картинками делаете не используя стандартных средств. Загружаются ли они из сети?

Answer (score 1):

Наверно неактуально уже, но [вот](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html)